# Find what cluster is being operated on from Connection object

Tags: web3.js, cluster, network

If I a have a `Connection` object from web3js, is there a way I can determine from this if it is operating on mainnet or devnet (or some local network)? The only thing in this direction I could think of was to check it's `rpcEndpoint` property against some known rpc urls for which I know if they are on mainnet or devnet. This is not portable and breaks as soon as someone uses a different endpoint I don't have saved. Is there a general solution for this?

Edit: I'm basically looking for a reverse `clusterApiUrl` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the rpcEndpoint includes the words mainnet-beta, devnet or testnet

Apart from that you could make a simple function that checks cluster nodes albeit it's a bit hacky

```
async function checkCluster(connection: Connection) {
  const mainnet = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'),"singleGossip");
  const devnet = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'),"singleGossip");
  const testnet = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('testnet'),"singleGossip");
 
 let nodes = await connection.getClusterNodes();
  switch (nodes[0].pubkey) {
    case (await mainnet.getClusterNodes())[0].pubkey:
      return "mainnet-beta"
    case (await devnet.getClusterNodes())[0].pubkey:
      return "devnet"
    case (await testnet.getClusterNodes())[0].pubkey:
      return "testnet"
    default:
      console.log("unknown error")
      return null;
  }
}
```

Checkout the [code](https://replit.com/@Maverick77/Reverse-clusterApiUrl-example?v=1)